# My function in Scala is returning the supertype and my type class can't handle it

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming, typeclass, implicit

I'm trying to go functional, but when working on real world problems I'm struggling, I need helps with a few basics. I like the idea of a type class and to add more implicit types in future.

```
      trait Query {
       def queryDetails: QueryDetails
      }

      case class LocalQueryType(queryDetails: QueryDetails) extends Query
      case class JdbcQueryType(queryDetails: QueryDetails) extends Query

      def queryTypeFactory(queryDetails: QueryDetails): Query = {
         queryDetails.platform match {
            case c if queryDetails.platform.contains("-file://") => LocalQueryType(queryDetails)
            case _ => JdbcQueryType(queryDetails)
          }
      }
```

Then I have a type class that looks for the local or Jdbc types, but it doesn't work as it is receiving only Query type.

I've tried using generics like:

```
     def queryTypeFactory[T<:Query](queryDetails: QueryDetails): T = {
         queryDetails.platform match {
            case c if queryDetails.platform.contains("-file://") => LocalQueryType(queryDetails)
            case _ => JdbcQueryType(queryDetails)
          }
     }
```

Adding Type Class:

```
trait QueryTask[A] {
  def runQuery(a: A): String
}

object QueryTask {

    def apply[A](implicit sh: QueryTask[A]): QueryTask[A] = sh

    object ops {
      def runQuery[A: QueryTask](a: A) = QueryTask[A].runQuery(a)

      implicit class ShowOps[A: QueryTask](a: A) {
        def runQuery = QueryTask[A].runQuery(a)
      }
    }

    implicit val localQuery: QueryTask[LocalQueryType] =
      instance(localQueryType => s"running local: ${localQueryType.queryDetails.command} on platform: ${localQueryType.queryDetails.platform}")

    implicit val jdbcQuery: QueryTask[JdbcQueryType] =
      instance(jdbcQueryType => s"running jdbc: ${jdbcQueryType.queryDetails.command} on platform: ${jdbcQueryType.queryDetails.platform}")

  def instance[A](func: A => String): QueryTask[A] =
    new QueryTask[A] {
      def runQuery(a: A): String = func(a)
    }
```

The idea is to not use the usual OO factory or strategy pattern.

Comment: What exactly was your idea here? There isn't any typeclass here. Also, I can see that the problem is that you would expect the return type of the function to be of the specific type, that is a runtime behavior that you can not know at compile time _(unless QueryDetails is a constant at compile time)_. Care to explain what you wanted to model here? How do you expect to use `queryTypeFactory`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've added the type class. The idea was to not use a factory pattern to create instance of a reader and pass them about, I thought a type class would be a good alternative, I thought I'd start small but got stuck straight away. The flow is to parse a bit of json and then generate a class with has database details inside, then have the correct type class use the case class to connect.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what is the problem? What doesn't work, why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Type class approach seems not to work in your use case.

Implicits are resolved at compile time. So in order to decide which instance you need `QueryTask[LocalQueryType]` or `QueryTask[JdbcQueryType]` compiler has to know whether type `A` is `LocalQueryType` or `JdbcQueryType` at compile time.

But it seems you decide that depending on whether `queryDetails.platform.contains("-file://")` or not i.e. at runtime.

It seems you need usual pattern mathing. You should use type class pattern when it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Probably much easier just to pass a function around.